# Interaction of div sections behaves different with FFox and all other Browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox

FFox renders interaction of horizontal div table and lower vertical div tables different from all other browsers. This is a recent problem 7/2015. In all browsers tested other than FFox, the vertical list onder the horizontal menu is left justified as called out in the CSS. But in FFox it is justified to the right of where ever the horizontal menu ends. I reduced the WEB html to a specific CSS interaction of 2 div sections. 
In the code below, the "widemenu" height and font effect the problem. However I do not understand why. Increasing the "widemenu" height from 30 or reducing the font size fixes the problem, but I want to know why. I'm new to SO so I hope I did this right.

```
<head>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
#tblmenu table{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 85px;
    /*clear: both;*/
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

#widemenu ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#widemenu {
    background-color: #FFD98F;
    height: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="widemenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">HorListItem-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">HorListItem-2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="tblmenu">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>    <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>A&nbsp;Column</b></td>    </tr>
    <tr>    <td align="center" width="85%"><a href="">Column Item</a></td>  <td>(Count)</td>    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You did do this right, although a link to a jsfiddle (or similar) containing the same code would have been useful. I have addressed your question in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in the font rendering of different browsers. The height of the floated li elements depends on the height of the line of text that they contain, which in turn depends on the way that the font metrics are interpreted and values rounded by the browser.

The height of those li elements in your example is about 30px. In Firefox, they're fractionally more than 30px, in the other browsers they're either exactly or less than 30px.

So when the browser looks to position the table, it first attempts to put it next to the earlier floated items. In the other browsers, the height of the ul, consumes all the space beside the li elements, and so the browser then starts from the left again and puts the table on the left.

In Firefox, the height of the ul element almost, but not, quite consumes the space beside the li elements, so the table is positioned below the ul but beside the li elements.

So increasing the height of the ul element fixes the problem by consuming the space beside the li elements, while reducing the font-size makes the li elements height smaller, so the again all the space beside is consumed.

To ensure that the table is not positioned at all next to the li elements, use the `clear` property on the element following the floated li elements. So just add

```
#tblmenu {
    clear:left;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ghpope6x/1/ for a working example.

---

<sub>Rather than use a height for the ul element, you might prefer to use a "clearfix" on that element. Clearfixes are covered in great detail both on SO and the wider web.</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much. I had an inkling of where the problem was, but this makes it clear. There are sooo many CSS options! Ill add clear or clearfix...